# int cannot be converted to string?

Tags: java, string, integer

I am trying to write the instructions to notice when circle is about to be 12 and then add 1 to square.

The code below works fine for me

```
   int x = Integer.parseInt(circle.getText()); 
   x = x + 1;
   String z = Integer.toString(x);
   circle.setText(z);
```

However, I am having trouble with these new instructions I am trying to write.
How can I get square, convert to integer, add 1 and then put the value back?

```
   int q = Integer.parseInt(square.getText());
   x = q + 1;
   square.setText(x);
```

Comment: setText(x) takes String as argument. Your x is `int`.

Comment: The answer is in the first snippet: convert the int to a String.

Comment: In the first snippet you do `Integer.toString(x)`. In the second you do not. Why do you think it's not required.

Answer (score 8):

You can convert to `String` using `Integer.toString()` :

```
square.setText(Integer.toString(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
square.setText(x+"")
```

Will work

Answer (score 0):

Why would an `int` be convertible to a `String` (unless an implicit conversion exists, which is not the case, there is not a lot of implicit things with the Java compiler, primitive wrappers and string concatenation apart) ?

Use one of these two options :

```
square.setText(String.valueOf(x));
square.setText(x + "");
```

Comment: honestly... I'm kind of new to Java as well and didn't understand (and really I still don't) why something that can be printed to the screen doesn't have an implicit conversion. I know you said Java omits a lot of conversions that happen implicitly in other languages, but why do they? It doesn't seem like you lose any data... Could you possibly update your answer to shed some light on this?

Comment: Printing things out and concatenating strings is a special case where the compiler will automatically add string conversions, but that's the only place. Everywhere else, you have to use types rigorously.

Answer (score -1):

Using your own code
String z = Integer.toString(x);
square.setText(z);

Comment: Same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828052/2227743